# How to read the same data from excel sheet to the textfile in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlrd, xlwt

This code actually is working fine but the output showing is different because the excel sheet were present in some values like int, float but after running the script the output showing like given below. I dont need .0 with that value. I want exact values which is there in input.

```
  Rows  Column  2   6
   a    cd  21
   b    cd  11  4
   c    cd  22  3
   s    cd  4.1 2
   e    cd  4   1
```

This is the code which showing some wrong value

```
import xlrd
import xlwt
workbook=xlrd.open_workbook("xxx.xls")
sh=workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
print sh.nrows
print sh.ncols
n=0
i=0
file=open("xx.txt","w")

for n in range(sh.nrows):
    for i in range(sh.ncols):
        data =sh.cell_value(n,i)
        print  data,
        file.write(str(data)+" ")
    print 
    file.write("\n")
```

Please help me for this issue. I need that whatever it is in excel that should be present in out.
This is the output for the above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel treats all numbers as **floats**.  So `xlrd` is reading all of them as floats and giving them as it is.

A simple workaround for this is to check if a `cell` has a `float` data type & has no floating value, then convert it to `int` type.

```
if isinstance(cell, float) and cell.is_integer():
    cell = int(cell)
```

So, your code becomes, something like this.

```
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('data.xls')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
num_rows = worksheet.nrows 
num_cells = worksheet.ncols 
curr_row = -1

with open("xxx.txt", "w") as fh:
    for row in range(num_rows):
        for column in range(num_cells):
            data = worksheet.cell_value(row, column)
            if isinstance(data, float) and data.is_integer():
                data = int(data)
        fh.write(str(data) + " ")
    fh.write("\n")
```

And the output will be:

```
Rows Column 34.5 6
a cd 54 5
b cd 22.3 4
c cd 56 3
s cd 677.1 2
e cd 32 1
```

**Note:** If your input file has floating numbers like `6.0` they will be converted to `6` by default.

Comment: actually in this excel if you have the boolean value like true or false , the output shows as 1,0. but i wants that true or false. Take example above of the question and code and input

Comment: @Raj `true` or `false` are string objects. They will be same in both input & output file.

Comment: No., you take same input and use one more column for true or false.when you are reading the data from excel using our scripts the output showing like 0's and 1's.i need the same true or false i dont want 0 and 1., this is the issue ., please try it